# the usage of "will"

Tags: meaning

> "We Don't Want To Kill Any Of You. But, Trust Me, We Will."

this is a famous line from ***Dutch Van der Linder***,one of the protagonist in ***Red dead:Redemption2***
it took place when the gang had tried hard to halt the train , and Dutch warned the people in the train in a coercive tone.

I wonder the usage of "will" here in the end of the line,what does "we will" means here?
does it  mean:"we **can**" to suggest a possibility(if they don't do what dutch tell them to),or something else I don't know.
please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "will" in this case is an auxiliary verb denoting future tense. Because the main verb is already mentioned in the first sentence, is is omitted in the second (and to enhance the dramatic effect ;) ). A complete version of the statement could be something like

> We don't want to kill any of you. But, trust me, we *will* kill you.

The future tense using "will" typically means that something will happen for sure. So there's no doubt that the speaker will kill the recipient. He will not try it, he doesn't plan to do it, but he *will*. No room for doubt.

Comment: So basically Dutch was threatening them and  to necessarily kill them eventually no matter what,right?

Comment: @vaterherrn Dutch told them what was going to happen, regardless of what anybody wanted or did.